# First and Last name in Excel given inconsistent data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am receiving a list of names on a daily basis that are inconsistently formatted, and I need to get them into a last name, first name format. Sometimes they have a middle name, sometimes they have a full middle name, sometimes they have a nickname in quotes.

I'm pretty close to the answer, but I'm having trouble with last names that have a space. Currently I am considering everything before the first space to be the first name and everything after the last space to be the last name. See below for sample list and what I would need them to look like:

```
Martin Van Buren = Van Buren, Martin  
John Quincy Adams = Adams, John  
Martin Luther King = King, Martin  
John Jay = Jay, John  
F. Scott Fitzgerald =  Fitzgerald, F.  
W.E.B. Du Bois = Du Bois, W.E.B.  
John F. Kennedy = Kennedy, John
```

Comment: you won't be able to get Van Buren as a first name with out Quincy Adams also being a first name

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no rule which could let Excel know that "Van" and "Du" are part of family name, so you need to list them.

I find regular expressions to be very convenient for this type of tasks. As Excel doesn't support them by default, you need to look for an add-in.

Now I picked [this free one](https://www.domwoodman.com/posts/how-to-get-excel-in-regex/), and here I can use this formula (my previous favorite doesn't work with 64 bit Excel):

`=RegExpFind(B1,"((Van|Du) )?[^ ]+$")&", "&RegExpFind(B1,"^[^ ]+")`

Just complete the list as you find more examples.

How it works:

- last name:https://regex101.com/r/6WM7DF/1
- first name: https://regex101.com/r/SFdEUd/1

[image]